# Library for drawing Japanese calligraphy

Tags: ios, graphics, drawing

I'd like to make a drawing software for Japanese calligraphy on iOS like following page.
http://www1.mahoroba.ne.jp/~matumoto/msyoS.html

So, I'm looking forward some libraries for drawing Japanese calligraphy.

Of course, it's OK the library is not compatible for iOS, though.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Why don't you just download some handwritten japanese fonts?

Comment: Because I'd like to let user draw his own calligraphy with his finger in the app.